# Increase AsyncTask stack size?

Tags: android

The Android sdk allows customizing the stack size of non-ui threads using something like this:

```
ThreadGroup group = new ThreadGroup("threadGroup");
new Thread(group, runnableObject, "YourThreadName", 20000).start();
```

Is there a similar call that can be made that allows me to use the `AsyncTask` api with a increased stack size?

Comment: To clarify, I'm performing an operation in an AsynchTask which throws a Stackoverflow excpetion. If I perform the operation in thread created with code similar to that which I posted, the stack does not overflow. I was hoping that I could similarly increase the stack size of the AsyncTask through the provided api (or some not terribly ugly overriding of the AsynchTask class).

Comment: My answer was edited and a solution was added to use your custom executor with custom stackSize of threads.

Comment: I will accept your answer as it looks like it should do the job. I might not implement it though, because it looks like a slightly risky way to solve a relative corner case (my stackoverflow exception is rare). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AsyncTask` has a private static object (an anonymous inner class) of `ThreadFactory` to generate new a `Thread` [1]:

```
private static final ThreadFactory sThreadFactory = new ThreadFactory() {
    private final AtomicInteger mCount = new AtomicInteger(1);

    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        return new Thread(r, "AsyncTask #" + mCount.getAndIncrement());
    }
};
```

as you can see its `newThread` method returns a `Thread(Runnable runnable, String threadName)` without any parameter of `stackSize`. So you couldn't change it. However, stack size in a thread has a highly platform-dependent interpretation. It may even be ignored completely [2].

**Edit** you can use your custom executor rather than `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` of `AsyncTask` which uses `sThreadFactory`. For example:

```
private static final int CPU_COUNT = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
private static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = CPU_COUNT + 1;
private static final int MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = CPU_COUNT * 2 + 1;
private static final int KEEP_ALIVE = 1;

private static final ThreadFactory yourFactory = new ThreadFactory() {
    private final AtomicInteger mCount = new AtomicInteger(1);

    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        ThreadGroup group = new ThreadGroup("threadGroup");
        return new Thread(group, r, "YourThreadName", 20000);
    }
};

private static final BlockingQueue<Runnable> sPoolWorkQueue =
        new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(128);

public static final Executor YOUR_CUSTOM_THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR
        = new ThreadPoolExecutor(CORE_POOL_SIZE, MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE, KEEP_ALIVE,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS, sPoolWorkQueue, yourFactory);
```

then, you can use your custom executor:

```
new AsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(YOUR_CUSTOM_THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, Params);
```

---

[1] https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java

[2] http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html

Answer (score 0):

All AsyncTasks are controlled internally by a shared (static) ThreadPoolExecutor and a LinkedBlockingQueue. When you call execute on an AsyncTask, the ThreadPoolExecutor will execute it by running internally a new thread or queueing it. So threads stack sizes are controlled by inner ThreadPoolExecutor. You don't have access to it. If you want to control stack sizes use your own ThreadPoolExecutor. However as @yaa110 stated stack size parameter is highly platform-dependent.